# how to iterate in n-arrays in a loop python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I am a new python programmer, and I need some help with this task.

I have n-arrays like:

```
t0=array([])
t1=array([])
...
tn=array([])
```

I want to load n-txt files, and save one of the columns in these files into the tn arrays above defined. Due the large value of n, I want to do something like:

```
### deternime the number of files to use
n=1000

### create the tn empty arrays
for i in range(n):
   time ="t"+str(i) + " = []"   
   exec(time)

### load the .aei files, and save the column 0, into the tn corresponding 
### array

for i in range(n):
    l = np.loadtxt('ast%i' % i +'.aei', skiprows=4, usecols=(0,4,5)).T
    t'%i' %i=append(t'%i' %i,l[0])
```

Thus, I want to save:

in t0 array the column 0 extracted from ast0.aei

in t1 array the column 0 extracted from ast1.aei

in t2 array the column 0 extracted from ast2.aei

...
and so on

In the second for-loop is the line that I dont know how to do it and does not work:

```
t'%i' %i=append(t'%i' %i,l[0])
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Note: my falies are named as ast0.aei,ast1.aei,...,astn.aei

Comment: Do you really want n seperate arrays? Maybe it is easier to put the results in a list?

Comment: Hi Forzaa, yes, I want n separate arrays. Thanks!

Comment: Well, in my opinion it would be easier to put the arrays in a list. You can simply select `t[0]` to get array `0`, instead of writing `t0`. This is also much more convenient when you want to loop over the arrays.

Comment: Hi Forzaa, you are right! It's easier in your way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a list of arrays. Something like this could work

```
t = []
for i in range(n):
    l = np.loadtxt('ast%i' % i +'.aei', skiprows=4, usecols=(0,4,5)).T
    t += [l]
```